# Sum of Function defined on Subsets

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I want to know if their are any fast approaches to solve the following problem. I have a list of codes somewhere in the thousands `(A0, A1, A2, ...)`. There is a positive value attached to about a million distinct combinations `(A0-A1, A2-A10, A1-A2-A10, ...)`. Let the values be denoted `f(A0-A1)`. Note that not all the combinations have the value attached.

For each listed combination, I want to calculate the sum of values of the values attached to each set that contains the given combination. For instance, for `A2-A10`,
calculate

```
g(A2-A10) = f(A2-A10) + f(A1-A2-A10) + ...
```

I would like to do this with minimal time complexity. A simpler related problem is to find all combinations where `g(C)` is greater than a threshold value.

Comment: Maybe something like this? You can construct a poset of all subsets with positive value attached, ordered by inclusion. Then, think of it is a lattice, and process from top to bottom, tallying cumulative sum of supersets values with a kind of dp approach.

Comment: One still has to keep track of inclusion-exclusion somehow.

Comment: The inclusion exclusion is one problem I was running into.

Comment: [This](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/736/given-a-weighted-dag-is-there-an-ove-algorithm-to-replace-each-weight-with-t) may be useful, although it tires to solve a more general problem.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem This is a different problem indeed. We don't have an explicit DAG here. We can build a "flat" one (equal to its transitive closure) in O(n^2\*m) (n is number of combinations, m is number of codes)

Comment: @n.m. I agree, I included the above reference thinking that there may be a solution for the special case when the dag has a small diameter, e.g. at most m.

Comment: When you reach a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful answers and accept the best (even if you have to write it yourself).  This allows Stack Overflow to archive your question.

Answer (score 1):

Key the existing combinations with a bit map, where bit `n` denotes whether A`n` is in that particular coding.  Store the values keyed by the bit map for each in your favorite hash-map structure.  Thus, f(A0, A1, A10, A12) would be `combo_val[11000000001010000...]`

To sum all of the desired combinations, build a bit map of your root.  For instance, with the combination above, we'd have `root = 1100000000101000` (cutting off at 16 total elements for the sake of illustration.

Now simply loop through the keys of the hashmap, using `root` as a mask.  Sum the desired values:

```
total = 0
for key in combo_val.keys()
    if root && key == root
        total += combo_val[key]
```

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Isn't this just an efficient way to loop over all million records?

Comment: Yes, it is ... so far.  The bit map also allows more effective indexing, depending on the language in use.  Brute-force iteration is ... well, brute force.

Comment: It took me a long time but I came up with something that is generally better than brute force.

Answer (score 0):

I thought waaay too long before coming up with the following approach.

Index the million combinations. So you know which you want.  In your example:

```
0: A0-A1
1: A2-A10
2: A1-A2-A10
```

For each code, create an ordered list of combinations that contain that code.  Call that `code_combs`.  In your example:

```
A0: [0]
A1: [0, 2]
A2: [1, 2]
A10: [1, 2]
```

Now we have a combination of `codes`, like `A2-A10`.  We create two arrays, one of codes, the other of indices.  Set indices at 0.  So:

```
codes = ['A2', 'A10']
indices = [0, 0]
```

And now do the following:

```
while not done:
    let max_comb = max(code_combs[codes[i]][indices[i]] over i in range(len(codes))
    Advance each index until we are at the max_comb or greater
        (if we reach the end of any list, we are done)
    If all are at the same max_comb, we add its value.
    Advance all indexes by 1.
        (if we reach the end of any list, we are done)
```

Basically this is a k-way intersection of ordered lists.  Now here is the trick.  If we advance naively, this will be slightly faster because we only have to look at combinations that contain a code.  However we can use a clever advance strategy like this:

```
Advance by 1, 2, 4, 8, etc until we reach or pass the point we want.
Do a binary search between the last two values until we find the point we want
```

(Be warned, implementing binary search is not always so easy to get right.)

And now we are crossing fingers.  But if any one of our codes has few combinations that it is in, and there aren't too many codes in our combination, we can compute our intersection quite quickly.